# inet6 addresses

Tags: networking

I saw this on one of my machine:

```
~$ ifconfig
eth3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:1a:a0:9d:c9:90  
          inet addr:192.168.1.100  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:a412:573:557c:ce58/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:21a:a0ff:fe9d:c990/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::21a:a0ff:fe9d:c990/64 Scope:Link
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad::c68/128 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:41f0:3be9:2668:e5b/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fddc:2a53:4ad:0:4daf:e298:e54c:2540/64 Scope:Global
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:217764 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:402733 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:21329905 (21.3 MB)  TX bytes:40208000 (40.2 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:fdfc0000-fdfe0000
```

Why does this interface has so many inet6 addresses? Could someone explain the details of this interface metrics? Thanks.

Comment: Someone has: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address